# Facebook customer javascript chat show only click button

Tags: javascript, facebook

I integrated the facebook customer chat to my website. i want to show it only after visitor clicked the button. After click it show the messenger icon and the dialog. Here my code but it don't work. What's wrong?

```
<!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            xfbml            : true,
            version          : 'v6.0'
          });
          FB.CustomerChat.hide();
          FB.CustomerChat.hideDialog();
        };

        (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/hu_HU/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

      <!-- Your customer chat code -->
      <div class="fb-customerchat" attribution=setup_tool page_id="100956841486197" theme_color="#EE0000" logged_in_greeting="Hello! Ez itt a DebrecENNI Bevásárlás messenger chat. Segíthetünk valamiben?" logged_out_greeting="Hello! Ez itt a DebrecENNI Bevásárlás messenger chat. Segíthetünk valamiben?"></div>

<script>
$(".fb-message-blue").click(function(){
      FB.CustomerChat.show();
      FB.CustomerChat.showDialog();
});
</script>
```

Comment: _“What's wrong?”_ - well first of all, that would be _“it don't work”_ as a problem description. Please go read [ask], and then edit your question, and add a proper one.